# How do I deal with auto block users?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition

Extremely annoying to deal with.  I've tried using throws, focus attacks, and spd's, and these work well on D level opponents, but once you get into C and above, it seems nearly every player uses autoblock, and abuses it to advantage.

Since each on autoblock is effectively punishable, it makes it annoying when I really want to get damage in.  It's annoying to know that, on console, it would actually hit, but on the 3DS, it just lets them absorb damage then punish.

How do I deal with auto-block users? I've also tried filtering users to Pro-mode users, but it takes nearly forever just trying to find a match in the same region with the same controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm completely mistaken about how Autoblock works, your best bet is to use vulnerability frames.

Simply wait for the player to make any sort of move that leaves them open to attack, and exploit it.  Feel free to block the entire rest of the match - it's not like *they* are doing anything else.

This is extremely annoying since they user is basically given frame-perfect blocking between each move, cutting their vulnerability time down severely.  But it's the only way you have to get at them, and you may as well learn how to exploit vulnerability frames anyway if you intend to go past Rank C.

In addition, if they try to use their perfect blocking to edge their way in, force them to keep their distance with short jabs and kicks.  This keeps your own vulnerability frames down while giving them minute tick damage.

Comment: Autoblock is a 3DS specific feature that allows user to take temporary damage (like when absorbing damage with Focus attacks), and is extremely annoying since there is no hitstun, so any attack on autoblock is punishable

Comment: @memescientist Good lord that's horrible.  I don't think there **is** an answer to that then, except to become the monster that uses Autoblock.

Comment: So far I've been using SPD's to take out C and lower players, but even A players in the game use Auto-block (i assume they are sick of fighting others with it)